# How to force 4 digit year format in <f:convertDateTime>

Tags: date, jsf-2, converters

I am using JSF 2.0 and RichFaces 4. For the date input, I am trying to force the pattern `mm/dd/yyyy`.

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.startDate}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="mm/dd/yyyy"/>
</h:inputText>
```

When user actually enters a date with a 2-digit year like so `mm/dd/yy`, then the converter automatically converts the year to 4 digits. This is undesired. How can I stop it from doing that without creating a custom converter? Is this a bug in the JSF converter?

Comment: `<f:convertDateTime/>` uses `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`, so it will use whatever SimpleDateFormat compatible pattern you specify with the `pattern` attribute.  If you want a two digit year, then use `mm/dd/yy`.  If you want the field to support multiple formats, then the standard `<f:convertDateTime/>` converter is not what you want.  I'm not aware of any multi-format converters, but I don't see why one couldn't be done.  It sounds a little funny to me though.  What is the problem with the year being converted to a 4 digit year?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't a bug. That's just how [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) works. Here's a cite of relevance from the linked javadoc:

> - **Year**: If the formatter's `Calendar` is the Gregorian calendar, the following rules are applied.
>
>   - ...
>   - For parsing, if the number of pattern letters is more than 2, the year is interpreted literally, regardless of the number of digits. So using the pattern "MM/dd/yyyy", "01/11/12" parses to Jan 11, 12 A.D.
>   - ...

The JSF [`<f:convertDateTime>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/convertDateTime.html) is just using it under the covers. Your best bet is to extend the [`DateTimeConverter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/DateTimeConverter.html) and validate the length of the submitted value before passing through to the real `DateTimeConverter`. You can't go around creating a custom converter, but it's after all fairly simple.

```
@FacesConverter("myDateTimeConverter")
public class MyDateTimeConverter extends DateTimeConverter {

    public MyDateTimeConverter() {
        setPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value != null && value.length() != getPattern().length()) {
            throw new ConverterException("Invalid format");
        }
        return super.getAsObject(context, component, value);
    }

}
```

Use it as follows:

```
<h:inputText ... converterMessage="Please enter date in MM/dd/yyyy format">
    <f:converter converterId="myDateTimeConverter" />
</h:inputText>
```

Please note that I fixed the `mm` (minutes) in the pattern to be `MM` (months).

Comment: i will just extend the converter like you exampled,thank you! BalusC!